# python mechanize find_link find the final matching link

Tags: python, mechanize

I've got a page with >=1 links with "Display charges" in the text. 
I can find the first such link with

```
firstLink = br.find_link(text_regex=re.compile("Display charges"),nr=0)
```

I'd love to be able to find the final link. I hoped this would work

```
lastLink = br.find_link(text_regex=re.compile("Display charges"),nr=-1)
```

but in the case of only one matching link, it's failing.

Please note: Python and mechanize beginner but have discovered help(mechanize.Browser) which was a big breakthrough :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `br.links()` to generate all such links, then use `list(...)[-1]` to pick off the last one:

```
lastLink = list(br.links(text_regex=re.compile("Display charges")))[-1]
```

For example:

```
In [29]: import mechanize

In [30]: import re

In [31]: br=mechanize.Browser()

In [32]: br.open('http://www.example.com')
Out[32]: <response_seek_wrapper at 0xa2b59ec whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0xa2b554c whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0xa3143ac>>>

In [33]: br.links()
Out[33]: <generator object __call__ at 0xa289af4>

In [34]: list(br.links())
Out[34]: 
[Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/', text='Homepage[IMG]', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/domains/', text='Domains', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/domains/')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/numbers/', text='Numbers', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/numbers/')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/protocols/', text='Protocols', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/protocols/')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/about/', text='About IANA', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/about/')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/go/rfc2606', text='RFC 2606', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/go/rfc2606')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/about/', text='About', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/about/')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/domains/', text='Domains', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/domains/')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/protocols/', text='Protocols', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/protocols/')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/numbers/', text='Number Resources', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/numbers/')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='http://www.icann.org/', text='Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'http://www.icann.org/')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='mailto:iana@iana.org?subject=General%20website%20feedback', text='iana@iana.org', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'mailto:iana@iana.org?subject=General%20website%20feedback')])]

In [35]: list(br.links(text_regex=re.compile("About")))
Out[35]: 
[Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/about/', text='About IANA', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/about/')]),
 Link(base_url='http://www.iana.org/domains/example/', url='/about/', text='About', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/about/')])]
```

Comment: This helped me get started with mechanize. Thanks!